# What is the Best practices of working with Dockerized Django and RDS?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rds

I am working on developing a Django app that will use RDS Postgres as a production DB, I will containerize the web app in docker. What is the best way to set up a local development environment that works with the DB, and at the same time it has data like production?

Comment: Either have two `settings.py` files and select the right one or read the database connection details from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) boilerplate template which follows best practise and has docker option while building project.